# Restarting Puppet Enterprise Master after hiera.yaml change

Tags: puppet, ubuntu-14.04, puppetmaster

I have `Puppet Enterprise 3.3.1` installed on an Ubuntu box.  I've updated `hiera.yaml` to reflect a different datadir, and according to the docs a restart is required.

How should restart the puppet master?

When I try

```
service pe-puppet restart
```

It says

```
* Restarting PE puppet Agent
```

Not the master.

Answer (score -2):

Use the following syntax to restart the server in stead of the agent:

`service pe-puppetserver restart`  or
`service pe-puppetmaster restart`

Comment: pe-puppetserver isn't a valid service

Comment: Use the following syntax to restart the server in stead of the agent:

service pe-puppetserver restart or service pe-puppetmaster restart